# Listview-android total not reflecting correctly when item in removed from listview

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-listview, adapter

Whenever items from listview are added or deducted the total should be updated. When I add items from listview the grand total is correct but when items are deslected the price of the product shd be deducted from grand total which is not happening. Any solutions?

```
adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();

            int index = selectedList.indexOf(ordList.get(adapter.recentItemSelected));
            if (index >= 0) {
                selectedList.remove(index);
                rvOrderBrdAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
                return;
            } else {
                selectedList.add(ordList.get(adapter.recentItemSelected));
                rvOrderBrdAdapter.notifyItemInserted(selectedList.size() - 1);

                return;
            }
        }
    });
public void totalOrderValue(ArrayList<OrderBrdDataModel> filteredlist) {
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < filteredlist.size(); i++) {
        total = total + filteredlist.get(i).getBrdIndividualTotal();
    }
    totalValue.setText(String.format("%.3f", total));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.. Any other solutions  welcomed.. had to call  totalOrderValue(selectedList); inside my "if" block